# Basic Gradients with Dot Products of Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

This is mostly a notation question.

Given $f(x) = <b,x>$, is the gradient, $\nabla f(x) = b$?

Also, given $g(x) = <Ax,x>$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive-semi definite matrix, then $\nabla g(x) = 2Ax$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is not the gradient which is $\nabla$. Apart from that the answers are positive to both of your questions.

Comment: Whoops, correcting now